# Loss of color when executing git through python

Tags: python, windows, git

I have the following git extension script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

if len(sys.argv) <= 1:
    sys.argv = sys.argv + ['status']

git_cmd = 'git ' + ' '.join(sys.argv[1:])

print('--->', git_cmd)

#p = Popen(['git'] + sys.argv[1:], shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
p = Popen(git_cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()

print(out)
#print(str(out).encode('ascii'))
#print(out.decode('ascii'))
```

Basically I want to get the output of my Git command in a variable but I also want it to preserve the terminal color codes in the variable. So when I call `print(out)`, it should print the colors too. Currently the string given back to me after calling `communicate()` does not have color information. If I remove `stdout=PIPE` from `Popen()`, then I do get colors, but the output goes directly to the output and I do not get it in a variable.

I'm running Python 3.4 rc2 on Windows through msysgit (not cmd.exe). So for example I will do this:

```
git index status --short
```

The command it runs is `git status --short`, the output contains no color information, but when I run the same command directly in msysgit terminal, it gives me colors.

Anyone know how I can get the color information back?

Comment: Note that the answer I gave doesn't take into account any Windows-specific behavior which may/may not exist.

Comment: Also, using a `git_cmd` string (which implies `shell=True`) is bad form. Pass in an explicit argument array, and don't set `shell=True`, if you want better-defined behavior (where you don't run the risk of `cmd.exe` parsing your command line incorrectly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `color.ui` to `always` in your git configuration.

Note that this will break quite a lot of scripts (which, in general, don't expect color codes interspersed in content they're reading from `git` subcommands).

To update this temporarily, you can pass `-c color.ui=always` on the command line, or set the `GIT_CONFIG` environment variable to point to a config file with this setting only when your script is in operation.

---

Alternately, you can just stop using `stdout=PIPE`, output will be direct to the TTY instead of captured by your program (which is sensible, as your program is doing absolutely nothing with it other than printing), and git will colorize by default.

Comment: My script isn't done yet but ideally I plan to mutate the output a bit before I print it. That's why I wanted colors.

Comment: ...well, then, the first part of this answer should be useful to you. Of course, your code doing the mutation work will need to know how to handle terminal codes. (If you're only **ever** targeting Windows, you may only need to know how to handle ANSI terminal codes; if you're targeting other platforms as well, that gets considerably more complicated).

Comment: You can also add a `-c color.ui=always` argument between `git` and the actual command (or two separate strings in the array, which as already noted, sidesteps parsing issues).  That might be easier than adjusting config files.